# Como saber a licença de um dado módulo no ERP PRIMAVERA V9

Tags: c#, vb.net

Há algum método na API do PRIMAVERA ERP v9 para saber se determinado cliente tem licença de bancos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ERP PRIMAVERA para poderes saber que modulo/sub-modulo é que está licenciado podes usar o serviço da API do modulo da gestão comercial:

```
 "bso.Comercial.LicencaGcp.Bancos.Base”
```

Nesta classe "LicencaGcp" podes ter acesso a tudo o é o licenciamento dos submodulos em modo leitura.

Espero ajudar.

Comment: Sim ajudou. Obrigado.